# [RUNTIME ERROR]: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, logistic-regression

I’m working on a classification problem. I’m trying to classify URLs as malicious or benign. I’m implementing logistic regression for this problem, and here is my code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.utils.data
from torch.autograd import Variable

class LogisticRegressionModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_dim, num_classes):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_dim, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear(x)
        return out

class Train(LogisticRegressionModel):


    def __init__(self, in_dim, num_classes, lr, batch_size):
        super().__init__(in_dim, num_classes)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.learning_rate = lr
        self.input_layer_dim = in_dim
        self.output_layer_dim = num_classes
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        self.model = LogisticRegressionModel(self.input_layer_dim, self.output_layer_dim)
        self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.model = self.model.to(self.device)
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr = self.learning_rate)  

    def epochs(self, iterations, train_dataset, batch_size):
        epochs = int(iterations/(len(train_dataset)/batch_size))
        return epochs

    def train_model(self, training_data, n_iters):
        batch = self.batch_size
        epochs = self.epochs(n_iters, training_data, batch)
        training_data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = training_data, batch_size = batch, shuffle = False)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            for i, data in enumerate(training_data):

                X_train = data[:, :-1]
                Y_train = data[:, -1]

                if torch.cuda.is_available():
                    x = Variable(X_train).cuda()
                    y = Variable(Y_train).cuda()

                else:
                    x = X_train.float()
                    y = Y_train.type(torch.LongTensor)

                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                out = self.model(x).data
                loss = self.criterion(out, y)
                loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()

batch_size = 1000
train_class = Train((training_set.shape[1]-1), number_of_target_labels+1, 0.001, batch_size)
rain_class.train_model(training_set, batch_size)
```

However, I get the following error when I run this code block:

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

I don't know why that is the case. If you'd like to have a look at my Notebook and the dataset, here is the link to it: https://github.com/islamaymansais/Malicious-URL-Classifier

This is a classification project to classify URLs as benign or a malicious category (phishing, defacement, spam, malware). Let me know if you have any questions that I can clarify.

Comment: remove '.data' from out = self.model(x).data ; it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right. I removed .data and it resolved the error. However, i wanted to see what my loss was by printing it. First iteration it was 10.9814, second iteration was 4.1855, then every iteration after that my loss was nan. Is that normal?

Comment: This could happen because of any number of reasons. You can try decreasing learning rate  or apply gradient clipping. Normalizing your data might also help. Another possible solution could be applying non-linearity like relu after linear layer. Here's a similar [issue](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nan-loss-coming-after-some-time/11568/2)